# Is there a way to check which template file is being loaded, if it is not a page template file?

Tags: templates, conditional-tags

I don't see any way of testing which template file is being loaded, if the template file is not a page template. Otherwise I would use is_page_template().

For instance, I am using a home.php template file to pull in the content from multiple pages(don't ask), how would I check that home.php is the template file being used when viewing the sites root url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just type in some text like "Debug" into the non-Php area of home.php (the part not surrouded by ) and see if it appears. If so, you know that home.php is being used.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think this is common practice or that WP tracks such either. [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) are very flexible and usually sufficient to build conditional logic.

If you really need this I'd look into [`__FILE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) constant and [`debug_backtrace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php).

Answer (score 0):

We can see the template file name in body tag by doing a view page source like *page-templatesfront-page-php* in WordPress twenty twelve theme. If we need to check in code, then [get page template slug](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_template_slug).

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this correctly - I usually echo this somewhere in header.php, to see which template is being used.

`<?php echo get_current_template(true);?>`

Comment: It will show template only if it is a page template... But OP clearly wants to show template name if it is not a page with custom template...