# Checking whether template part is loaded in a page

Tags: conditional-tags, get-template-part

I have a template part like this:

```
<nav id="subpagemenu" class="sidebar">
    <?php get_template_part( 'nav', 'subset' ); ?>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</nav>
```

Both of these are conditional, I mean, nothing will load if there's no content.  if there is content, they both load boxes like:

```
 <div class="widget">
```

Now I would like to be able to know if there are any widgets (sidebar, or my template_part), so that in my functions.php, I can set a variable $mywidgets=true or false.

I know that I can use '_is_active_sidebar' for the one part, but how can I check the other part?  I don't want to register that part as a sidebar...  All I need is a 'true/false'.

I tried 'is_page_template' and 'set_theme_mod'.  I also looked at these threads:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366351/getting-dom-elements-by-class-name

[Is there a way to check which template file is being loaded, if it is not a page template file?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24852/is-there-a-way-to-check-which-template-file-is-being-loaded-if-it-is-not-a-page)

Am I thinking of this in the wrong way?  Need to construct the theme differently?

Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear what content you need to check for. What is in the file loaded by `get_template_part`?

Comment: It's extra div.widget that I make (to show subpages or posts in category.)  I used same class name for styling as real widgets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a global variable in your theme functions.php

```
global $mywidgets;
$mywidgets = false;
```

in your template part add

```
global $mywidgets;
$mywidgets = true;
```

and in your functions you can check if its set to true:

```
function my_function(){
    global $mywidgets;
    $mywidgets = true;
    if ($mywidgets){
       // YES Your template part is loaded
    }else{
       // NO Your template part is not loaded
    }
}
```

Comment: If I put the a function call after declaring the variables, then it works.  All this sidebar and stuff is in the footer, so I may have to get back to t his when I'm less braindead.

<?php
global $mywidgets;
$mywidgets = true;
my_function();
?>